# ALT Tab to another client window from RDP full screen session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

From inside a RDP full screen session, I would like to have a "ALT + tab" switching functionality which switches to next window in the RDP client computer, preferably with "Win + tab" key.

Is there any solution/ suggestion?

PS: the two step process of clicking ALT+CTRL+BREAK and then trying to use ALT + tab is known and is not a solution for me.

Any RDP utility using RDP virtual channel which achieves this purpose is also good for my purpose.

Comment: Just as a note (and this does not answer your question), in a Dell laptop, where the keyboard does not have a <Break> key, I could use <Fn>+B as <Break>, so simultaneously pressing <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<Fn>+B switched the RDP client between Full screen or windowed mode.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Do you want from withing the RDP window to switch to another window on the local or on the remote computer?

Comment: @harrymc - I want to have two different (not contrived) shortcuts available simultaneously. E.g., Alt+Tab switches between windows in the remote host, and Win+Tab switches between windows in the local computer.
As I understand, this is exactly what the OP requests.
In my example above, if I switch out of the RDP client, I would recover normal Alt+Tab behaviour in the local PC, until RDP comes to the foreground.
Alternatively, Win+Tab (or else) could switch windows in the remote PC, and Alt+Tab be kept for switching in the local PC. Whatever mapping, it should be minimally intrusive.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Alt-Tab will switch windows on the remote computer.  When you refer to the "client" computer, do you mean the local computer or the remote computer?  If you mean the local computer, then the only workaround I know of is to change the connection's keyboard setting (on the Local Resources tab) to "On the local computer".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: Thanks for this link. But I am not looking for this option. See my question again.

Comment: I thought you were looking for Alt+PgDn and Alt+PgUp Can you please clarify jhamu?

Answer (score 0):

just run Remote Desktop (MSTSC.exe) as administrator, then all the regular ALT+TAB, Winkey+R, etc work correctly.  i believe all the "new" shortcuts only apply to the full screen "windows 8 app" remote desktop.  if you want to use mstsc.exe in desktop mode like normal, you have to run it as admin for the keys to work correctly.  yes, even if you disable UAC in control panel, only way to really disable UAC in windows 8 is through policies.

Answer (score -1):

mstsc.exe > Options > Local Resources > Keyboard > Apply Windows key combinations

Change from "Only when using the full screen" to "On this computer".

Comment: Would this provide two window-switching shortcuts available simultaneously (one for switching in the remote PC and the other for switching in the local PC)?

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same issue. To fix:

1. Run mstsc from commd
2. Click options at the bottom
3. Go to local resources tab
4. Go to keyboard setting and set "only when using the full screen"
5. Then connect